# Perl -- how to scroll new web page to previous line position

Tags: javascript, html, perl

After a perl script creates a new web page, is there something like `(goto-char previous-position)` -- e.g., before generating a new page, record current line number where the user is at and store it as a variable (i.e., `previous-position`) and then scroll to that same position after creating a new web page?

---

**EDIT**:  Here is something I found Googling that seems to be related.  If the page position can be recorded as a variable and passed to the script and executed when the new web page is loaded, then perhaps that would be a viable solution:

The HTML way is to declare the following where you want to scroll to:

```
[HTML]<a name="somename">[/HTML]
```

then the page could be scrolled to that automatically by accessing e.g.

```
[HTML]http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourpage.html#somename[/HTML]
```

The javascript way is to use scrollTo with the co-ordinates from the left and top to where you want to scroll to, e.g. Expand|Select|Wrap|Line Numbers

```
window.scrollTo(0,100);
```

To achieve this on page load, use on body onload

```
[HTML]<body onload="window.scrollTo(0,100); ...>[/HTML]
```

or define a function and call that instead.

Comment: Instead of voting to close, how about steering me in the right direction?  With my reputation of 3,304, I obviously have some programming experience.  Take a look at my questions and answers in my user history, and you will all see that I am no slouch.

Comment: If I understand the question, this can be generalized to "How do I maintain state between HTTP requests?" Is that an accurate interpretation of your question in more general (and searchable) terms?

Comment: @DavidO -- yes, something like `re-search-forward` from the top of the webpage would be sufficient if I could record a pattern near to the line number of a link that was previously clicked by the user.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean by line numbers, search forward, etc.  It sounds like you might want to render some portion of a page, and then on next request render the next portion of a page.  That will involve breaking your page into chunks that are still complete HTML documents, then setting a cookie that upon retrieval reveals which chunk has already been sent to the client, and which should be sent next.

Comment: @DavidO -- if the user clicks a link anywhere between lines 55 to 100, I'd like the new webpage to load and then automatically scroll to line 55.  If the user clicks a link anywhere between lines 200 to 250, I'd like the new webpage to load and then automatically scroll to line 200.  It's possible that cookies may be the answer, and I'll have to do some more reading on that issue.

Comment: So after reading your update and the most recent follow-up, I'm thinking this is a JavaScript question tagged as Perl.

Comment: @DavidO -- Well, if it is not possible to have the perl script execute something like `http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourpage.html#somename` when generating a new webpage, then perhaps javascript would be a viable alternative.  This solution, however, seems to be ideal (if possible) -- i.e., `http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourpage.html#somename`

Comment: The question has been solved using perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in perl / html was so simple that everyone missed it and assumed it had to be javascript.  All we needed to do was add an anchor in the html (e.g., `print '<a name="form_anchor"></a>';`) and place `&#form_anchor` at the tail end of the perl script parameters.  [A different solution is available in javascript, but I prefer including the solution in the existing perl script.]

NOTE:  Anchors could easily be set up for every link desired, so that when clicking the link, the appropriate parameter is passed to the perl script.

At some point I will revisit this answer and revise / redact it into a more simple example -- however, it is late at night and the script set forth below works exactly as I had hoped.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);

# ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
# yasnippet

my $yasnippet_dir = '/home/lawlist/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.snippets/lawlist-tex-mode';

my $yasnippet_query = new CGI;

my $selected_file_yasnippet = $yasnippet_query->param('selected-file-yasnippet');

my $yasnippet_selected_file = $yasnippet_dir . "/" . $selected_file_yasnippet;

# ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
# forms

my $form_dir = '/home/lawlist/.0.data/forms';

my $form_query = new CGI;

my $selected_file_form = $form_query->param('selected-file-form');

my $form_selected_file = $form_dir . "/" . $selected_file_form;

# ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
# header

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

open(FILE,'/home/lawlist/www/header.include.shtml') and print <FILE>;

# ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
# yasnippet

print <<HTML;

<table bgcolor="#990066" width="100%" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=6 border=0>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 border=0>
<tr>
<td>

<table width="100%" bgcolor="#000000" cellpadding=2>
<tr>
<td align=center>
<table width="100%" border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#990066" HEIGHT=25 align=center><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" COLOR="#FFFFFF" size=3><b>Yasnippet -- Code Snippets</b></font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>

<table width="100%" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
<tr>
<td rowspan="1" width="25%"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" color="#000000" size=3>

HTML

opendir(DIR, $yasnippet_dir) or die $!;

while (my $yasnippet_selected_file = readdir(DIR)) {

  next if ($yasnippet_selected_file =~ m/^\.|exclude-filename\.txt/);

  next unless (-f "$yasnippet_dir/$yasnippet_selected_file");

  next unless ($yasnippet_selected_file =~ m/\.txt|.el|.yasnippet$/);

  print '<a href="/cgi-bin/code-snippet.cgi?selected-file-yasnippet=' . $yasnippet_selected_file . '">' . $yasnippet_selected_file . "</a>" . "<br>\n<br>" . "\n\n"; }

closedir(DIR);

if ($selected_file_yasnippet) {

  open (DATA, $yasnippet_selected_file) or return $self->print_json_error($self->language('ERR_CANNOT_OPEN', $yasnippet_selected_file->{selected-file-yasnippet}, $!));

  read (DATA, my $yasnippet_selected_file, -s DATA);

  close DATA;

  print '</td><td rowspan="1" width="75%"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" color="#000000" size=3>';

  print '<pre class="brush:  lisp">' . "\n\n" . $yasnippet_selected_file . "\n" . '</pre>';

  print "\n\n<br>\n";

  close FILE; }

print <<HTML;

</font>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- end of cream color table -->
<!-- end of red border table -->

<hr COLOR="#CCCCCC" size=1 NOSHADE>

HTML

# ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
# forms

print <<HTML;

<table bgcolor="#990066" width="100%" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=6 border=0>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 border=0>
<tr>
<td>

<table width="100%" bgcolor="#000000" cellpadding=2>
<tr>
<td align=center>
<table width="100%" border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#990066" HEIGHT=25 align=center><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" COLOR="#FFFFFF" size=3><b>Forms -- Code Snippets</b></font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>

<table width="100%" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
<tr>
<td rowspan="1" width="25%"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" color="#000000" size=3>

HTML

opendir(DIR, $form_dir) or die $!;

while (my $form_selected_file = readdir(DIR)) {

  next if ($form_selected_file =~ m/^\.|exclude-filename\.txt/);

  next unless (-f "$form_dir/$form_selected_file");

  next unless ($form_selected_file =~ m/\.txt|.el|.yasnippet$/);

  print '<a href="/cgi-bin/code-snippet.cgi?selected-file-form=' . $form_selected_file . '&#form_anchor' . '">' . $form_selected_file . "</a>" . "<br>\n<br>" . "\n\n"; }

closedir(DIR);

if ($selected_file_form) {

  open (DATA, $form_selected_file) or return $self->print_json_error($self->language('ERR_CANNOT_OPEN', $form_selected_file->{selected-file-form}, $!));

  read (DATA, my $form_selected_file, -s DATA);

  close DATA;

  print '</td><td rowspan="1" width="75%"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" color="#000000" size=3>';

  print '<a name="form_anchor"></a>';

  print '<pre class="brush:  lisp">' . "\n\n" . $form_selected_file . "\n" . '</pre>';

  print "\n\n<br>\n";

  close FILE; }

print <<HTML;

</font>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- end of cream color table -->
<!-- end of red border table -->

HTML



# ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

  open(FILE,'/home/lawlist/www/footer.include.shtml') and print <FILE>;


exit 0;
```